# Does noexcept apply to exceptions propagating from initializer lists

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, noexcept

Lets say I have a constructor like so

```
Something(SomethingElse) noexcept : member{SomethingElse, something_that_might_throw()} {
    ...
}
```

Is a `noexcept` okay in this case if the construction of `member` can throw?  In the above example the member variable `member` is of a type I do not know.

On a side note: Are there other edge cases one needs to worry about when using `noexcept`?

Comment: @personwhodownvotedme what was wrong with this question?

Comment: Don't people you don't know. There is user with the display name`downvoter`.

Comment: @VeniVidiVici i dont think notifications are sent to a user if they do not have any activity in the question?

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici Difference between what?

Comment: But seriously what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Are absolutely sure that they are not notified? Does the site actually know when the user has even been seen on a post when it's handing out notifications? I actually did not downvote.

Comment: @VeniVidiVici I know because there are several users with the same username.  How would SO distinguish between them OR would the send notifications to all of them?  Also if you like the question you can always upvote it :)

Comment: I didn't think of that.

Comment: Why would you think it should be okay for this constructor to promise to not throw if the constructor called (explitibly or implicitly) for one of its bases or a members doesn't make the same promise?

Comment: @Walter Ill update the question.  You are right; the question as is sort of does not make sense when you consider the piece of code

Comment: Seems to be a good reason (for someone) to downvote ... (I upvoted, though).

Comment: @Curious Member or base makes absolutely no difference here.

Comment: @Walter What do you mean?  The member can be an instance of a type that is passed in via a template?

Comment: Well if the base constructor can throw then `noexcept` is not really suitable, `std::terminate` would be called anyway in such a case.

Comment: @Curious when you use the C++ tag, you will always get down-voted for no reason, get used to it! :)

Comment: @Curious Are you aware that `noexcept` can take a parameter to make it conditional? http://ideone.com/K8exMY

Comment: @kfsone I was!  I just wanted to make sure I was getting this concept right!  For example the things that confused me is that it is okay to mark something as `noexcept` if the construction of the function parameters throws as that is not really a part of the function body.

Answer (score 9):

**#UPDATE:**(Based on your edit): The original answer applies to everything within the *block-scope* of the function (constructors inclusive, including *constructor-initialization-list*). Why don't you [try](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/933cdad224b23a2a) the code and see. :-)

---

**#Original Answer**

```
Something(SomethingElse) : member{SomethingElse} noexcept {
    ...
}
```

Your code would not compile that way. `noexcept` comes before the colon `:`

```
Something(SomethingElse) noexcept : member{SomethingElse} {
    ...
}
```

To your question:

> Is a noexcept okay in this case if the `member` class constructor can
>   throw?

No, it's [not okay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec). The `noexcept` specifier is a promise that an exception will not leave that function or constructor. Should it leave, the runtime will terminate your program.

> If a search for a matching exception handler leaves a function marked
>   `noexcept` or `noexcept(true)`, `std::terminate` is called immediately.

This applies to the constructor.

---

**Despite the `try..catch` block**, the code below gets terminated:

```
struct Base {
    Base(){}
    Base(int){ throw int(5); }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived(int a) noexcept : Base(a) {}
};

int main()
{
    try{
        Derived d(45);
    } catch(...) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
bash: line 7:  7454 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c6b9c790664897a)

But if you remove the `noexcept` specification, you wouldn't abruptly end your program, exception handling will continue normally. :-).

I'll leave you to think of the consequences if you do this kind of thing in production or even a large code base with many contributors. Do not use `noexcept` if you are unsure of the exception guarantees of all the statements in your function/constructor block

---

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `noexcept` on a constructor applies to base class/member construction.

If you need to deal with such a case, you probably want to use the little-known (and rarely used) `function try block`. The syntax looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class bad_initializer {};

int do_throw() { 
    throw bad_initializer();
    return 1;
}

class something { 
    int member;
public:
    something() noexcept
        try : member{do_throw()} // <-- initializer list
        {
            // ctor body goes here
        }
        catch(bad_initializer const &) { 
            std::cerr << "initialization threw\n";
        }
};

int main() { 
    something s;
}
```

Now, the bad news: since you have a member that wasn't constructed, the `catch` block really has only a few options. Normal processing can't continue--an exception happened in constructing the object, which means the object can't ever finish construction. By the time you catch the exception, there's nothing you can do about that.

If it weren't `noexcept`, it could catch the exception, then do some processing (release any resources it did acquire successfully) then either rethrow the exception it caught, or throw a different exception (one that better reflected its inability to be constructed).

In this case, your meaningful choices are even more restricted: you can call `terminate` directly, or you can throw an exception, which will call `terminate` indirectly. About all the whole `try`/`catch` thing has done in this case is give you a chance to do a little processing before `terminate` gets called.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I had no idea that existed!

Comment: But it seems like you missed the definition of the `something()` constructor right?

Comment: @Curious: no--but I've added some comments to clarify.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**In general it's not okay, but in certain circumstances it may be**

`noexcept` is a promise, similar to the `const` qualifier of member functions, but unlike `const` it's not enforced at compile time (the compiler will not issue an error and perhaps not even a warning, if a `noexcept` function may actually `throw`, but see below). Thus, you can declare a function `noexcept` even if a compiler-generated check would find that this function may throw and the code will compile (otherwise your question would be impossible).

However, that defeats the purpose of `noexcept`. The main purpose is to indicate (1) to the programmer that they can use a certain functionality without worrying about exception safety, and (2) to the compiler that it does not need to add code for stack unwinding. Instead, if an exception is thrown in a `noexcept` function, the run-time will invoke `std::terminate()`, as required by the standard.

So, in general your constructor should only be `noexcept`, if all its functionality, including the construction of bases and members is too.

However, there is an exception. If you know that some method will never throw given any input *possible in the particular situation*, even if it may throw under other circumstances and hence not be `noexcept`, you can call this method in a `noexcept` situation. For example,

```
// requires non-negative x, will throw std::runtime_error for negative x
int my_func(std::int64_t x);

struct my_struct {
  std::int64_t q;
  my_struct(int x) noexcept : q(std::int64_t(x)*std::int64_t(x)) {}
  int member() const noexcept { return my_func(q); }  // fine: q>=0
};
```

In the situation of your post, this means if `member(somethingelse_type)` is not `noexcept`, but you know (from conditions outside the code snipped in your post) that no exception will be thrown for the particular argument provided in this circumstance, you may declare `Something(SomethingElse)` `noexcept`.

Comment: This is not correct. The spec requires that if a function marked `noexcept` throws an exception, the program is immediately terminated by a call to `std::terminate`. It's not merely a comment, or an "unenforced promise". See section 15.4 in c++11 standard, especially 15.4.10. I see that you've later tried to include this and reconcile it with your answer, but your first paragraph is misleading and I have to downvote.

Comment: @ChrisBeck  I understood "some method will never throw given any input possible in the particular situation, even if it may throw under other circumstances" to mean that the function  could theoretically throw but no possible imput that will be actually given to it will be one that throws.  In which case you, the programmer, knows that it is actually noexcept after all.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @ChrisBeck What are you ranting about? I did say (end of my 2nd paragraph) that a `throw` from a `noexcept` function will invoke `terminate()`. So what is not correct? Please be more precise.

Comment: @Walter: Well you changed the answer now, but what set off the rant was the part about `noexcept` is an unenforced promise. I don't doubt that you understand it but I think that's not a good way to explain it.